# How do you change the colour of the status bar with a button?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, statusbar, uistatusbar

I'm trying to implement a button that changes the background of my app from white to black along with the colour of the status bar. Right now I have

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know of a way of changing the colour of the status bar font without reloading the entire view?

Comment: @ ESchlotter Add this in your project's info.plist <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
 <false/>

Comment: It worked, Love you <3

Comment: :) You can upvote this comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set status bar style, application level then set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `NO` in your `.plist` file.

if you wan to set status bar style, at view controller level then follow these steps:

1. Set the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `YES` in the `.plist` file, if you need to set status bar style at UIViewController level only.
2. In the viewDidLoad add function - `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate`
3. override preferredStatusBarStyle in your view controller.

-

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Set value of .plist according to status bar style setup level.
[image]